# Could there be an issue with the max. memory capacity? Or why is this variable partly released?

Tags: objective-c, memory, max, capacity

I'm developing an iPad app and I ran into a really weird issue here. I'll try to explain it as good as possible.

I have a class named `TranslationObject` which is holding a key and a textual value. I have created this class as the following:

```
@interface TranslationObject : NSObject {
    NSNumber *_key;
    NSString *_value;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *key;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *value;

- (id) initWithKey:(NSNumber *) key andValue:(NSString *) value;

@end
```

The translations will be pulled from a XML or DB in the future, but for now I do the following:

```
@interface Translation : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *m_extfeat;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *extfeat;

+ (Translation *) getInstance;
- (id) init;
- (NSMutableArray *) getExtFeat;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation Translation

@synthesize extfeat = m_extfeat;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        m_extfeat = [[self getExtFeat] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableArray *) getExtFeat {
    TranslationObject *obj1 = [[[TranslationObject alloc] initWithKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 0] andValue:@"Animal house"] autorelease];

    .... more items declared ....

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7, obj8, obj9, obj10, obj11, obj12, obj13, obj14, obj15, obj16, obj17, nil];

    return [array autorelease];
}
@end
```

These translations are being used in a `UITableViewController` and are being fetched in the `viewDidLoad` method as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     _data = [[Translation getInstance].extfeat retain];
}
```

I use these values at its `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, where I call a method to configure the cell:

```
- (void) configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    TranslationObject *object = (TranslationObject *) [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Crashes here at 13th item:
    NSLog("Object key: %@", [object.key stringValue]);
}
```

As the snippet above says, strangely, the app crashes when fetching the key value **only if the _data array contains more than 12 items**. So if I only fill the _data variable with 12 items or less, my code works fine. If I add more than 12, the app crashes as soon as it fetches the 13th object.

So I enabled NSZombies and so when I check the 13th item in that method, the **value** is still fine, but it's only the **key** that turned into a Zombie. And again.. Only from the 13th item on!

Does anyone know how this is possible? Is it maybe so that there is a maximum number of items that can be stored in the memory? Is the memory full at the 12 item? But if that'd be the case, then why would the **value** still be there. How would it be possible that it's just the **key** that is being released before?! And how?!

I hope this explanation makes sense and someone can shine a light over this case.. =/

Thanks!

**EDIT: Here's the implementation of the initWithKey method of the TranslationObject:**

```
- (id) initWithKey:(NSNumber *) key andValue:(NSString *) value {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }
```

return self;
}

Comment: Can you post `TranslationObject`'s `initWithKey:andValue:` implementation?

Comment: Please post the code of `-[TranslationObject initWithKey:andValue:]`. There's likely to be a memory management issue in there.

Comment: what does the init method for TranslationObject look like - that is important

Comment: I edited my post and added the initWithKey implementation... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your using the property accessors in the `TranslationObject` or retaining the number:

```
@implementation TranslationObject

@synthesize key=_key, value=_value;

- (id) initWithKey:(NSNumber *) key andValue:(NSString *) value {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.key = key;  // ensures key is retained
    self.value = value;

    return self;
}

…

@end
```

### Specifics:

```
self.key = key;
```

is the syntax for calling the accessor methods for the property; in this case the set accessor.  Given you declared your property with the `nonatomic` and `retain` attributes as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *key;
```

the set accessor will look something like

```
- (void)setKey:(NSNumber *)value {
    if (value != _key) {
        id old = _key;
        [value retain];
        _key = value
        [old release];
    }
}
```

The set accessor is automatically generated by the compiler when you added:

```
@synthesize key=_key;
```

Conversely, calling

```
_key = key;
```

simply copies the value of the pointer in `key` to `_key`, but does not `retain` the object referred to by `key`.  `TranslationObject` does not assume *ownership* of key.  If you did not want to use the accessor, the correct implementation would be

```
_key = [key retain];
```

Comment: I don't know how but writing `self.key = key` instead of `_key = key` fixed this problem! Can you explain the difference between the two? Because I'd say I'm assigning my local variable in my code too... =/ Thanks!

Comment: `self.key` uses the property accessor to assign the value of `key`; `_key = key` just copies the pointer from `key` to `_key`, but does not transfer ownership.